# Fill in missing timestamp values in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

SQL newby here looking for a bit of help in writing a query.

Some sample data

```
Time    Value
9:00    1.2
9:01    2.3
9:05    2.4
9:06    2.5
```

I need to fill in those missing times with zero - so the query would return

```
Time    Value
9:00    1.2
9:01    2.3
9:02    0
9:03    0
9:04    0
9:05    2.4
9:06    2.5
```

Is this possible in T-SQL?

Thanks for any help / advice ...

Comment: Outer join a table or cte containing all times.

Comment: Searching SO for `[tsql] missing values` might be a start. Joining with a tally (aka numbers) table is an alternative to generating the values in a CTE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses a recursive CTE to generate the list of times and then use `left join` to bring in the values:

```
with cte as (
      select min(s.time) as time, max(s.time) as maxt
      from sample s
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 1, cte.time), cte.maxt
      from cte
      where cte.time < cte.maxt
     )
select cte.time, coalesce(s.value, 0)
from cte left join
     sample s
     on cte.time = s.time
order by cte.time;
```

Note that if you have more than 100 minutes, you will need `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

Comment: Is there a `cte.time` column defined?

Comment: @KamilG. . . There is now.  Thank you.

Comment: For anyone try to run this in postgres, change `with cte as` to `with recursive cte as`, and `dateadd(minute, 1, cte.time)` to `cte.time + interval '1 minute'` .

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use  *recursive CTE* make calendar table and `OUTER JOIN` base on that.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  [Time] Time,
  Value float
);


insert into T values ('9:00',1.2);
insert into T values ('9:01',2.3);
insert into T values ('9:05',2.4);
insert into T values ('9:06',2.5);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
 SELECT MIN([Time]) minDt,MAX([Time] ) maxDt
 FROM T
 UNION ALL
 SELECT dateadd(minute, 1, minDt) ,maxDt
 FROM CTE
  WHERE dateadd(minute, 1, minDt) <= maxDt
)
SELECT t1.minDt 'Time',
       ISNULL(t2.[Value],0) 'Value'
FROM CTE t1 
LEFT JOIN T t2 on t2.[Time] = t1.minDt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7fcad/11/0)**:

```
|             Time | Value |
|------------------|-------|
| 09:00:00.0000000 |   1.2 |
| 09:01:00.0000000 |   2.3 |
| 09:02:00.0000000 |     0 |
| 09:03:00.0000000 |     0 |
| 09:04:00.0000000 |     0 |
| 09:05:00.0000000 |   2.4 |
| 09:06:00.0000000 |   2.5 |
```

Comment: I like this method. This gives you the ability to set up the base data needed to fill all the gaps and then joined with any available data.This is how I would have done it.