# Filling timestamp gap values for ECharts

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mariadb

I am a newbie to NodeJS and working on an IoT project which collects data from several devices and gets displayed on a web-based service with trending line charts using ECharts. The data is stored in MariaDB with an interval of seconds. (usually every 10 seconds)

Frontend requests below data format to display the line chart.

```
{
  "name": "Line Info",
  "timestamp": [
     "2021-12-23 08:19:07",
     "2021-12-23 08:19:17",
     "2021-12-23 08:19:27"
  ],
  "PowerInput": [
     3.05718,
     3.05718,
     3.05718
   ],
   "ProdRemaintime": [
     1.83674e-40,
     1.83674e-40,
     1.83674e-40
   ],
   ...
}
```

Thing is, when the device is inactive it stops sending and storing data into MariaDB. Therefore when the device goes online again there will be a time gap between consecutive data rows in MariaDB.

| # | TimeStamp | PowerInput | FinalDieDiameter | GearOilTemp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-23 09:50:58.585000 | 3.05718 | 2.05 | 33.8511 |
| 2 | 2021-12-23 09:51:08.586000 | 3.05716 | 2.05 | 33.8511 |
| **3** | **2021-12-23 09:51:18.588000** | 3.05712 | 2.05 | 33.8511 |
| **4** | **2021-12-23 09:54:10.346000** | 1.21436 | 2.00 | 30.4218 |
| 5 | 2021-12-23 09:54:20.331000 | 1.62327 | 2.00 | 30.4971 |

And that leads to ECharts displaying only from when it has data, not including the time when the device is offline. [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzkuK.png) 
(I've queried for data time span from 12/21/2021 15:00 ~ 12/22/2021 11:21, but in MariaDB I only have data until 12/21/2021 15:04:17.)

In order to let users see the trends of device going online and offline, I'm looking for solutions to fill the timestamp gap and also add nulls to the dataset.

```
{
  "name": "Line Info",
  "timestamp": [
     "2021-12-23 09:51:08",
     "2021-12-23 09:51:18",
     "2021-12-23 09:51:28", // add missing timestamp
     "2021-12-23 09:51:38", // add missing timestamp
     ... // add missing timestamp
     "2021-12-23 09:54:08", // add missing timestamp
     "2021-12-23 09:54:10",
     "2021-12-23 09:54:20"
  ],
  "PowerInput": [
     3.05718,
     3.05718,
     null, // add missing data as null
     null, // add missing data as null
     ... // add missing data as null
     null, // add missing data as null
     3.05718,
     3.05718
  ],
  ...
}
```

My previous solution was to collect all data within a time range first, then find the time gap and fill in missing timestamp and nulls by NodeJS, in order to produce a whole dataset for ECharts. But the performance is really bad when the time gap is huge. Are there any alternative ways to do this?

** I found this on StackOverflow: [Fill in missing timestamp values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625584/fill-in-missing-timestamp-values-in-sql), but I am limited to not using extra SQL memory, so creating a new table and joining them isn't an option for me.

I will appreciate any help on how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, MariaDB.  See `seq_1_to_10`

```
SELECT  "2021-12-23 09:51:08" + INTERVAL 10 * (seq-1) SECOND AS ts,
        li.PowerInput,
        ...
    FROM seq_1_to_99999 AS s
    LEFT JOIN `Line Info` AS li  ON li.timestamp = s.ts
    WHERE s.ts BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

There are 8640 10-second intervals per day.  The 99999 could be replaced by a suitable number.

However, I would expect even one day's worth of data to mostly choke a graphing program.  Consider summarizing the data into, say, 1-hour intervals for graphing purposes.  With that, you could add 'hi', 'lo', 'avg', etc.